# jQuery: How to check if certain checkboxes are checked, and change styles accordingly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been trying to figure this out, but am not sure in which way to approach it using jQuery. I have a table of classes, and according to the classes that are checked, I want to change the background of tbody to reflect that this requirements are met.

```
      <tbody>
          <tr class="active header">
            <th colspan="5"><b>Math (3 Courses)</b></th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>MAC2311</td>
            <td>Calculus I w/ Analytic Geometry</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="math" value="MAC2311"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>MAC2312</td>
            <td>Calculus II w/ Analytic Geometry</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>MAC2311 or MAC2281</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="math"value="MAC2312"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>MAC2281</td>
            <td>Calculus for Engineers I</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="math" value="MAC2281"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>MAC2282</td>
            <td>Calculus for Engineers II</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>MAC2311 or MAC2281</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox"  name="math" value="MAC2282"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Math Elective</td>
            <td>(Math Elective)</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>MAC2312 or MAC2282</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="math" value="math_elective"></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
```

so, for example, if MAC2311, MAC2312, and math_elective are checked, tbody's background color can change green to signify completion of the section.

Comment: You may like to create a sample on http://jsfiddle.net/ to make it easier for people who willing to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select all of the checked inputs with the `:checked` selector:

`$("input[type=checkbox]:checked")`

To see if any of the checkboxes are checked:

```
var isAtLeastOneChecked = ($("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length > 0);

if (isAtLeastOneChecked) {
    // color your tbody
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the change handler like

```
.selected {
    background-color: green;
}
```

then

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('input[name="math"]').change(function () {
        var $tbody = $(this).closest('tbody');
        $tbody.toggleClass('selected', $tbody.find('input[name="math"]:checked').length == 3)
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ELgrq/)

Here we adds the class `selected` to the tbody if there is 3 checked checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to assign ID's to your `input` and `td` elements.

`var MAC2311 = document.getElementById('idOfThatInput');`

`var 2311td = document.getElementById('idOftd');`

`if (MAC2311.checked)
("#2311td").css("background", "green");`

or use an `Array` containing the elements desired to be checked, and do the comparison in a `for` loop instead of individually.

Answer (score 0):

$(document).ready(function(){

```
$("#youTableId input").click(function () {

  //Now $(this) will point to the element that has raised the event
  and you can do something like this 
  alert($(this).is(':checked'));

  //Now you now $(this) is the element that raised the event.
  //You can get all the attributes of the element like name, id value, whether its check or not etc by using attr() function.

  $(this).attr("value");
});
```

}